Fail to dynamically instantiate AssetOperation in GoogleAds python client
Any idea how I can dynamically instantiate AssetOperation in GoogleAds python client?
I'm getting:
TypeError: 'AssetOperation' object is not callable

In code:
        for video_name, video_id in video_name_id_list:
            # Dynamically create an instance of AssetOperation
>           asset_operation = self.asset_operation_type(
                create={
                    'name': video_name,
                    'youtube_video_asset': {'youtube_video_id': video_id}
                }
            )
E           TypeError: 'AssetOperation' object is not callable

Here are my tries:

or:

When I use this:

